# Use htacess to send requests to two php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, url-routing

I am trying to redirect some requests to my website from index.php to another file called admin.php

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( strpos($page, '?') !== false ) {
    $page = strstr($page, '?', true);
}
$page = explode('/', $page);
$page = array_diff($page, ['']);
$page = implode('/', $page);
if ( !$page ) { $page = 'public/home'; }
$file = "pages/{$page}.php";
if ( !is_readable($file) ) {
    $file = 'pages/error/404.php';
}
```

This code selects the page selected from the user.
I have this two file using this code but looking in different folders.
How do I configure my .htaccess to redirect all the request to www.mysite.com/admin to the file admin.php and all the rest to index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Apache will serve *one* page at a time.

Options:

1. Do everything in either `admin.php` or `index.php`.
2. Do what you need in `admin.php`, save the rest into `$_SESSION`, return a 302 redirect to `index.php`.